# Track associations using Paper Trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, paper-trail-gem

I'm trying to use *paper trail* `gem` and I'm trying to use the experimental feature ([**to track associations**](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#4b-associations)).

First, here are my files (below the explanations):

*migrate/user_version:*

```
class CreateUserVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_versions do |t|
      t.string :item_type, null: false
      t.integer :item_id, null: false
      t.string :event, null: false
      t.string :whodunnit, null: false
      t.json :object
      t.json :object_changes, null: false
      t.index %i(item_type item_id)

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

*migrate/add_transaction_id_column_to_versions (default from paper trail):*

```
# This migration and CreateVersionAssociations provide the necessary
# schema for tracking associations.
class AddTransactionIdColumnToVersions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :user_versions, :transaction_id, :integer
    add_index :user_versions, [:transaction_id]
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :user_versions, [:transaction_id]
    remove_column :user_versions, :transaction_id
  end
end
```

*migrate/create_version_associations (default from paper trail):*

```
# This migration and AddTransactionIdColumnToVersions provide the necessary
# schema for tracking associations.
class CreateVersionAssociations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :version_associations do |t|
      t.integer  :version_id
      t.string   :foreign_key_name, null: false
      t.integer  :foreign_key_id
    end
    add_index :version_associations, [:version_id]
    add_index :version_associations,
      %i(foreign_key_name foreign_key_id),
      name: "index_version_associations_on_foreign_key"
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :version_associations, [:version_id]
    remove_index :version_associations,
      name: "index_version_associations_on_foreign_key"
    drop_table :version_associations
  end
end
```

Models:

*models/paper_trail/version:*

```
module PaperTrail
  class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PaperTrail::VersionConcern
    self.abstract_class = true
  end
end
```

*models/user_version (to store the versions of user):*

```
class UserVersion < PaperTrail::Version
  self.table_name = :user_versions

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :whodunnit
end
```

*models/user:*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail class_name: 'UserVersion'

  has_many :addresses, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true
end
```

*models/address:*

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail # <- The error is here

  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :addresses
end
```

*initializers/paper_trail:*

```
PaperTrail.config.track_associations = true
```

---

Explanation:

As you may have noticed, I'm using a custom version class **ONLY**, not the *default* versions...

The problem comes when I try to create/update an existent a nested model (in my case "address" using nested attributes).

Actual behavior: It saves the *user* and the **first** *address* so it throws the following error:

> TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):

If I remove the line `has_paper_trail` from `Address` *model* it works 100% without errors (but, of course, without versioning).

Am I missing something? Isn't the experimental feature compatible with "parent" custom version class?

PS#1: Please, note that I'm not trying to use a custom version class to **track associations**, I'm using the *default* associations_versions + custom version class (in parent, in this case "User") as described in docs.

PS#2: I didn't include the *controller* `code` because it's a basic configuration and it's working... the issue is in model that has paper trail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/961